# How to Drag/Drop a UIView (e.g. UIImageView) to a cell in a Table in iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, drag-and-drop

I already have the dragging and dropping of a UIImageView to another UIImageView but now I need to be able to drag/drop a UIImageView (that is situated beside a Table View) inside the Table View. So basically I need to determine where I "dropped" my Image on the Table View and determine what Cell or Row it was dropped and do something about it? Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForRowAtPoint:(CGPoint)point` ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html))

Comment: Hi Kreiri, Thanks for your answer. may I know how I will use above code? Sorry, I'm kind of noob in iOS, I'm coming from Android. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, when you drag and drop your image view to the table, you can get coordinates of point where you dropped it, correct? You'll need coordinates of this point relative to the table view (look at convertPoint:fromView: and convertPoint:toView: methods of UIView class), then you call  [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:thisPoint], and you get an NSIndexPath for the row in which this point landed.

Comment: Thank you very much Kreiri. After studying the concept of tables in iOS a little more (I swear I studied it before but I really haven't fully digested it) I was now able to make it work by following your code above :-) Again, Thank you very much!